VSCode keeps crashing within 1sec of starting up in ubuntu22.04
My VS Code suddenly started crashing within 1sec of starting up.
VS Code Version: 1.90.0
OS Version: Ubuntu 22.04
Running code --disable-gpu --disable-extensions --verbose
I've tried:
Reinstalling VSCode (using snap)
Run code
Run code --disable-gpu --disable-extensions
Run code --disable-gpu --disable-software-rasterizer
Reinstalling Nvidia drivers
Adding the verbose output
[0606/164932.193632:ERROR:directory_reader_posix.cc(43)] opendir /home/parth/.config/Code/Crashpad/attachments/6388c80a-e3dc-419c-8c84-75d2bda686a8: No such file or directory (2)
[95858:0606/164932.293515:WARNING:bluez_dbus_manager.cc(248)] Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable.
[95887:0606/164932.424709:WARNING:vaapi_wrapper.cc(1497)] Skipping nVidia device named: nvidia-drm
[main 2024-06-06T11:19:32.432Z] [File Watcher (node.js)] Request to start watching: /home/parth/.config/Code/User (excludes: <none>, includes: <all>, filter: <none>, correlationId: <none>),/home/parth/.config/Code/User/settings.json (excludes: <none>, includes: <all>, filter: <none>, correlationId: <none>)
[main 2024-06-06T11:19:32.453Z] Starting VS Code
[main 2024-06-06T11:19:32.453Z] from: /snap/code/160/usr/share/code/resources/app
[main 2024-06-06T11:19:32.453Z] args: {
  _: [],
  diff: false,
  merge: false,
  add: false,
  goto: false,
  'new-window': false,
  'reuse-window': false,
  wait: false,
  help: false,
  'list-extensions': false,
  'show-versions': false,
  'pre-release': false,
  'update-extensions': false,
  version: false,
  verbose: true,
  status: false,
  'prof-startup': false,
  'no-cached-data': false,
  'prof-v8-extensions': false,
  'disable-extensions': true,
  'disable-lcd-text': false,
  'disable-gpu': true,
  'disable-chromium-sandbox': false,
  sandbox: false,
  telemetry: false,
  debugRenderer: false,
  'enable-smoke-test-driver': false,
  logExtensionHostCommunication: false,
  'skip-release-notes': false,
  'skip-welcome': false,
  'disable-telemetry': false,
  'disable-updates': false,
  'use-inmemory-secretstorage': false,
  'disable-workspace-trust': false,
  'disable-crash-reporter': false,
  'crash-reporter-id': '752e7a7e-0c8b-4c3e-a32c-3d3dc02e1f9c',
  'skip-add-to-recently-opened': false,
  'open-url': false,
  'file-write': false,
  'file-chmod': false,
  force: false,
  'do-not-sync': false,
  trace: false,
  'preserve-env': false,
  'force-user-env': false,
  'force-disable-user-env': false,
  'open-devtools': false,
  'disable-gpu-sandbox': false,
  '__enable-file-policy': false,
  'enable-coi': false,
  'no-proxy-server': false,
  'no-sandbox': false,
  nolazy: false,
  'force-renderer-accessibility': false,
  'ignore-certificate-errors': false,
  'allow-insecure-localhost': false,
  'disable-dev-shm-usage': false,
  'profile-temp': false,
  logsPath: '/home/parth/.config/Code/logs/20240606T164932'
}
[main 2024-06-06T11:19:32.455Z] Resolving machine identifier...
[main 2024-06-06T11:19:32.455Z] Resolved machine identifier: 2cf85072c4bd13876d483f3ef88829cff176b041f0fef2ba320103764737430e
[main 2024-06-06T11:19:32.455Z] Main->SharedProcess#connect
[main 2024-06-06T11:19:32.459Z] [File Watcher (node.js)] Started watching: '/home/parth/.config/Code/User'
[main 2024-06-06T11:19:32.460Z] StorageMainService: creating application storage
MESA-LOADER: failed to open radeonsi: /usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
failed to load driver: radeonsi
[main 2024-06-06T11:19:32.463Z] update#setState idle
MESA-LOADER: failed to open kms_swrast: /usr/lib/dri/kms_swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
failed to load driver: kms_swrast
MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
failed to load swrast driver
[main 2024-06-06T11:19:32.465Z] ElectronURLListener: waiting for window to be ready to handle URLs...
[main 2024-06-06T11:19:32.465Z] lifecycle (main): phase changed (value: 2)
[95887:0606/164932.465935:WARNING:sandbox_linux.cc(418)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[main 2024-06-06T11:19:32.466Z] windowsManager#open
[main 2024-06-06T11:19:32.466Z] windowsManager#open pathsToOpen [
  {
    backupPath: '/home/parth/.config/Code/Backups/1717643223523',
    remoteAuthority: undefined
  }
]
[main 2024-06-06T11:19:32.467Z] windowsManager#doOpenEmpty {
  restore: true,
  remoteAuthority: undefined,
  filesToOpen: undefined,
  forceNewWindow: true
}
[main 2024-06-06T11:19:32.468Z] IPC Object URL: Registered new channel vscode:e407999f-78ef-4deb-9683-91a8ea3708ce.
[main 2024-06-06T11:19:32.469Z] window#validateWindowState: validating window state on 1 display(s) { mode: 1, x: 285, y: 95, width: 1028, height: 772 }
[main 2024-06-06T11:19:32.469Z] window#validateWindowState: single monitor working area { x: 0, y: 27, width: 1596, height: 871 }
[main 2024-06-06T11:19:32.469Z] window#ctor: using window state { mode: 1, x: 285, y: 95, width: 1028, height: 772 }
[main 2024-06-06T11:19:32.535Z] window#load: attempt to load window (id: 1)
[main 2024-06-06T11:19:32.542Z] windowsManager#open used window count 1 (workspacesToOpen: 0, foldersToOpen: 0, emptyToRestore: 1, emptyToOpen: 0)
[main 2024-06-06T11:19:32.542Z] lifecycle (main): phase changed (value: 3)
[main 2024-06-06T11:19:32.542Z] resolveShellEnv(): skipped (VSCODE_CLI is set)
[main 2024-06-06T11:19:32.568Z] [File Watcher (node.js)] ignoring a path for watching who's stat info failed to resolve: /home/parth/.config/Code/User/settings.json (error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/parth/.config/Code/User/settings.json')
[main 2024-06-06T11:19:32.596Z] resolveShellEnv(): skipped (VSCODE_CLI is set)
[0606/164932.596393:ERROR:process_memory_range.cc(75)] read out of range
[0606/164932.596420:ERROR:process_memory_range.cc(75)] read out of range
[0606/164932.596428:ERROR:process_memory_range.cc(75)] read out of range
[0606/164932.596444:ERROR:process_memory_range.cc(75)] read out of range
[0606/164932.596452:ERROR:process_memory_range.cc(75)] read out of range
...
...
...
...


Fixed this, the problem was with the snap version.
You can try removing currently installed version with
sudo snap remove code
Then download the version from VSCode official site (current version is 1.90.0), and install it with
sudo apt install ./code_1.90.0-1717531825_amd64.deb
Thanks for the answer @davsahakyan here https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/214445#issuecomment-2152118955

This is how I have solved the issue:

Uninstall the snap version of VS Code using the below command:
sudo snap remove code


Download the official .deb package:
wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > packages.microsoft.gpg
sudo install -o root -g root -m 644 packages.microsoft.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/packages.microsoft.gpg] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list'
rm -f packages.microsoft.gpg


Update the package cache and install VS Code:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install code


Verify if code has been installed successfully:
code --version




I had the same issue today. I reverted to the most recent version.
sudo snap revert --revision=159 code
Now it is working fine with all my previous data.

thank you so much! this is an critical error. has someone already reported?

Very welcome, yes you can find on https://askubuntu.com/
